# How to run a rubyfile with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, html

I wrote a Ruby script that removes several log files and sends a notification email via `Net::SMTP` afterwards.

**Questions**

- Can I put the output with the information on a webpage?
- Can I run the file in JavaScript?

Comment: No, we don’t know what you mean.

Comment: I want to run a rubyfile in JavaScript.

Comment: It is impossible to run anything “in Javascript.”

Comment: JavaScript cannot run the Ruby script itself (language limitations aside, JavaScript runs on the client side and the Ruby script has to access the server's file system and libraries), but it could make an API call to a web server which runs the Ruby script and returns the result. The server doesn't necessarily have to be written in Ruby, although that could be easier. Take a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com), it's very light-weight.

Comment: @Jaydie: Hint: if someone tells you they don't understand your question, merely repeating the question will not make it any clearer.

Comment: Complementing the other answer, yes, you can put the output of the ruby script in a web page. Probably you will need to parse it and give it an HTML format, depending on what is your output.

Comment: if you use Sinatra with streaming you can show the progress in realtime, google these words

Comment: @Stefan: Maybe the OP wants to use server-side JavaScript. Of course, unless the OP doesn't express himself more clearly, there is not much we can do.